# Erro ao setar propriedade do JQuery FullCalendar quando o usuário muda a data

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Eu necessito mudar a propriedade `minTime` da visão `agendaDay` do `FullCalendar` dinamicamente, conforme o usuário muda a data.

Eu já tentei o seguinte:

```
dayRender: function(event, element, view) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.minTime = '10:35:00';
        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
}
```

O valor *10:35:00*  é apenas um exemplo, pois minha aplicação retorna os valores reais da base de dados, dependendo da data que o usuário escolher.

Quando eu descomento a linha `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');`, para tentar dar um *refresh* na `view` após a alteração da propriedade, a página fica em branco, em consequência de algum erro.

O mesmo acontece se eu tentar dar *refresh* na `view` usando `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');`.

Qual seria a maneira correta de atualizar as propriedades do calendário e exibi-las quando o usuário muda a data?

Comment: Qual o log do console? (F12 ou Ctrl+J na maioria dos navegadores)